# groupby and return all rows of first n groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like below

```
>>> df.head()
       0      1       2          3   4           5                      6
0  35000  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000CE
1  35001  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000PE
2  35002  26000  OPTIDX      NIFTY  XX  1609425000      NIFTY20DEC10400CE
3  35003  26000  OPTIDX      NIFTY  XX  1609425000      NIFTY20DEC10400PE
4  35004  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499956200  BANKNIFTY1771321100CE
```

I want to group these in by column 5 in sorted order and return first n groups where n can be given as variable.

I did `df.sort_values(5).groupby([5])` i get `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x2afc8d0>`

How do I get all rows in first 2 groups. In the sample df above group 1 would be 1499351400, group 2 would be 1499351400 group 3 would be 1609425000

Expected output: when groups required =2

```
       0      1       2          3   4           5                      6
0  35000  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000CE
1  35001  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000PE
4  35004  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499956200  BANKNIFTY1771321100CE
```

Update1:After trying @jezrael's

```
>>> k2=k1[k1.groupby(5).ngroup() < 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 529, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'ngroup'
```

Additional: Is it possible to do it without pandas (only python), I may not always find machines with pandas on them. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) (working in `0.20.2`) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.sort_values(5)

print (df.groupby(5).ngroup())
0    0
1    0
4    1
2    2
3    2
dtype: int64

df = df[df.groupby(5).ngroup() < 2]
print (df)
       0      1       2          3   4           5                      6
0  35000  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000CE
1  35001  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000PE
4  35004  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499956200  BANKNIFTY1771321100CE
```

For oldier version of pandas use a little hack - information are hidden in object `grouper.group_info`, so select first array by `[0]`:

```
df = df.sort_values(5)

print (df.groupby([5]).grouper.group_info)
(array([0, 0, 2, 2, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2]), 3)

print (df.groupby([5]).grouper.group_info[0])
[0 0 2 2 1]

df = df[df.groupby([5]).grouper.group_info[0] < 2]
print (df)
       0      1       2          3   4           5                      6
0  35000  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000CE
1  35001  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000PE
4  35004  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499956200  BANKNIFTY1771321100CE
```

Alternative solution with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(5)
df = df[pd.factorize(df[5])[0] < 2]
print (df)
       0      1       2          3   4           5                      6
0  35000  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000CE
1  35001  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000PE
4  35004  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499956200  BANKNIFTY1771321100CE
```

Comment: ngroup is the number of groups right ? whos index starts from 0 right

Comment: Exactly, I add output for your data.

Comment: It is new function in last pandas version `0.20.2`. Mybe there is problem.

Comment: mine is 0.19.2, is there any other way than ngroup that might work in 0.19.2

Comment: Give me some time.

Comment: in `df[pd.factorize(df[5])[0] < 2]` what did [0] exactly do here

Comment: Factorize return 2 arrays as outputs, obviously need only first one, so select it by `[0]`. You can also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#factorizing-values)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `ngroup`, just rank the elements with `'dense'` and use that to index into df:

```
In [24]: df.loc[df[5].rank(method='dense') <= 2]
Out[24]: 
       0      1       2          3   4           5                      6
0  35000  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000CE
1  35001  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499351400  BANKNIFTY1770621000PE
4  35004  26009  OPTIDX  BANKNIFTY  XX  1499956200  BANKNIFTY1771321100CE
```

This works because `rank(method='dense')` gives us the sorted rank for each number seen:

```
In [25]: df[5].rank(method='dense')
Out[25]: 
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    2.0
Name: 5, dtype: float64
```

(P.S. In an odd coincidence, I added both `ngroup` and `method='dense'`, so this question makes me very happy. :-)

Comment: Thanks, why did we use .loc ? and not just `df[df[5].rank(method='dense') <= 2]`